# Gimbal rotation doesn't work with Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I've got the sample UWP app to work with my Mavic Air, I can see camera feed etc. Now I'm trying to change Gimbal angle like this:

```
var connected = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetGimbalHandler(0, 0).GetConnectionAsync();
// true

var attitude = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetGimbalHandler(0, 0).GetGimbalAttitudeAsync();
// pitch: 0, roll: 0, yaw: -124

var range = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetGimbalHandler(0, 0).GetGimbalAttitudeRangeAsync();
// pitch: max 17 min -90; yaw: max 0 min 0; roll: max 0 min 0;

var angle = new GimbalAngleRotation() { mode = GimbalAngleRotationMode.ABSOLUTE_ANGLE, pitch = -20, yaw = 10, roll = 0  };
var resp = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetGimbalHandler(0, 0).RotateByAngleAsync(angle);
// PARAM_OUT_OF_RANGE
```

As you can see, the range for yaw & roll is 0-0 (none). However, the actual yaw value is -124; In my understanding Mavic Air has a 3 axis gimbal, so I should have wider range for each axis.

Also, when I try to change yaw or roll I get PARAM_OUT_OF_RANGE response. Changing pitch only results in NO_ERROR response, but I see no difference in Gimbal angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, you can try the following steps to resolve it:

1. You also need to set the GimbalAngleRotaion.duration(measured in seconds) a non-zero value in the [GimbalAngleRotation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/GimbalHandler.html?search=gimbalanglerotation&i=0&#value_gimbalanglerotation_inline) struct to rotate the gimbal.
2. Currently, the Windows SDK doesn't support yaw and roll axises' Gimbal rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I do also have the same issue. I cannot see the Gimbal doing anything with the RotateByAngleAsync method. The only way I got the Gimbal doing anything is using the RotateBySpeedAsync. This wouldn't be an issue if this would work perfectly, but sometimes it also does nothing. It works 1 time out of 10. :-/. If it works - it works as long as I do not restart the application. Didn't figure out yet what do to "reset" it.

```
// Defined somewhere else
gimbalHandler = DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetGimbalHandler(0, 0);

// In my control method
var gimbalRotation = new GimbalSpeedRotation();
gimbalRotation.pitch = 4;
gimbalHandler.RotateBySpeedAsync(gimbalRotation);
```